# How can I create a VirtualBox disk in an EncFS drive?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

I'm trying to set up a VirtualBox image inside an EncFS drive on Windows 7 but it's failing with the following message:

> Failed to create the hard disk storage Z:\Mike_s Win 7 VirtualBox.vdi.
>
> Could not create the medium storage unit 'Z:\Mike_s Win 7
>   VirtualBox.vdi'.
>
> VDI: cannot create image 'Z:\Mike_s Win 7 VirtualBox.vdi'
>   (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED).
>
> Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004) Component: Medium
>   Interface: IMedium {29989373-b111-4654-8493-2e1176cba890}

At first glance this appears to be a permissions issue but I don't see why or how I can resolve it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running VirtualBox as an administrator?

Comment: @Chris Yes, running as admin.